# How to explain this bogus comment?

Tags: bug, comments

> this answers your question: stackoverflow.com/questions/8196796/… – [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4464707/martin), [some time ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27999772/logic-error-in-tictactoe-game#comment44388967_27999772)

The commenter has exactly 1 reputation and no posts. How come he was able to comment, if it requires 50 reputation?

Comment: It's easy. Aliens.

Comment: @rene: yeah, BoltClock called it; I didn't see a deleted answer but the system auto-converted.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is a "trivial answer converted to comment" automatically by the system, which for whatever reason [ignores the rep restriction for comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/233960/trivial-answer-converted-to-comment-should-not-bypass-the-50-rep-restriction).

You can tell by the fact that the link points to another question — only short answers that consist of an internal link are automatically converted to comments. Additionally, you can tell that this is done by the system and not a moderator because there is no deleted answer to be found; the system discards the answer and creates a comment in its place as the user attempts to post the answer.

Comment: But shouldn't we see the deleted answer though then?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ: The answer is never submitted - the system quietly swaps it out for a comment.

Comment: Ah that would explain it.

Comment: Ah, that's why, I looked for the deleted answer here too.

Comment: Hmm, that effectively means the poster can't reply to anyone mentioning him/her in the comment chain. Can that poster edit his post afterwards? Sounds like a loophole that can be used to circumvent the rep restriction.

Comment: @Bartek Banachewicz: Exactly. The whole thing seems poorly thought out IMO. I don't know why it exists.

Comment: Should I add [meta-tag:feature-request] to that, or can it be left as-is right now? (#someta)

Comment: [The whole auto-conversion thing is bollocks anyway](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/99096/155739). :)