# How can someone comment on another post without 50 reputation?

Tags: bug, comments, privileges

While surfing Stack Overflow I see something unusual just now. I saw [some user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4579829/clemensoe) has [commented on a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28608756/strings-from-csv-file-into-multidimensional-array#comment45521732_28608756) without 50 reputation points.

My immediate reaction is to check whether the rules has changed. But apparently [it isn't](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

I know you can comment without having 50 reputation if

- It is your question
- Or your answer

But it isn't the case here. So my question is how come it is possible for him to comment?

Is this bug or loophole in the system? Or a different rule which I was not aware of?

Comment: Auto-conversion of an answer. They tried posting that as an answer and since it was basically a link to a SO post it was automatically converted to a comment.

Comment: @bluefeet I see. Interesting. I wasn't aware of that feature. What are the exact rules? do MSE talks about this feature? You may post it as a answer.

Comment: I think this has been discussed but I'm looking for a post about it

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284949/what-the-rules-for-the-trivial-answer-converted-to-comment, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272265/how-did-someone-with-1-rep-post-a-comment/272267#272267, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283838/how-to-explain-this-bogus-comment/283839#283839 are a few related posts I was able to find, and this question is a dupe of at least one of them. Hope they answer your questions about how this works. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been discussed on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/107063/how-could-a-user-with-1-reputation-point-leave-a-comment). This appears to be a case where the [answer was automatically converted to a comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/98950/answer-appears-automatically-converted-as-a-comment).

From [Kevin's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/98955/164200):

> Trivial answers containing a link to another question in the network are automatically converted to comments on the question

In this case, the user tried to post a link to another SO post with not much else so it became a comment even though they don't have the required 50 rep.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate question. I searched with keyword "less than 50 reputation" but duplicate question used "1 reputation". I think that's why I didn't find it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No worries, took me a bit to find a duplicate as well.